# Have single-threaded app block till a specific event occurs and then resume

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, .net-4.0

I am writing a single-threaded script to make a bunch of programmatic changes to a database.
Certain actions cause the database to perform some internal actions that take a while to fully resolve.

At the moment, my code includes a method that looks like this:

```
public static void AwaitTemplatePropagation(this Connection conn, DBObject template)
{
    while ((int)template["TransactionCount"] > 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Basically, it polls every 100 milliseconds until the outstanding transaction count reaches 0.

However, it is also possible to subscribe to an event called PropertyUpdated on the DBObject class, which will be raised when the TransactionCount property changes. I would prefer to use this and have the server let me know when to continue, rather than polling. I imagine it should look something like this:

```
public static void AwaitTemplatePropagation(this Connection conn, DBObject template)
{
    template.PropertyUpdated += ???; // Something?

    template.RegisterForPropertyUpdates(new string[] { "TransactionCount" });

    // Magic happens?

    template.UnregisterPropertyUpdates(new string[] { "TransactionCount" });
    template.PropertyUpdated -= ???; // Unsubscribe the event handler
    // Return to the calling function in the main thread
}
```

What I am having trouble figuring out is, how do I write a function which simply sets up the subscription, then *blocks* until a PropertyChangedEvent fires which says "the TransactionCount is now zero"? At that point I want to remove the subscription and return execution to where I was in the middle of the main script.

I'm using .NET 4.0, so async/await keywords aren't available. I'm not sure they would help anyway.

Comment: BTW, you can use `async`/`await` on .NET 4.0, if you install the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ManualResetEventSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private static ManualResetEventSlim _event = new ManualResetEventSlim (false);

public static void AwaitTemplatePropagation(this Connection conn, DBObject template)
{
    template.PropertyUpdated += OnPropertyUpdated; // Something?

    template.RegisterForPropertyUpdates(new string[] { "TransactionCount" });

    // Magic happens?
    // if you are using this method many times you have to reset the event first
    _event.Reset(); //Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, which causes threads to block.
    _event.WaitHandle.WaitOne();

    template.UnregisterPropertyUpdates(new string[] { "TransactionCount" });

    // Return to the calling function in the main thread
 }

public void OnPropertyUpdated(...)
{
    _event.Set();
}
```

[ManualResetEventSlim  performance](http://geekswithblogs.net/vitus/archive/2010/04/15/net-4-slim-style-performance-boost.aspx)

Comment: Are there significant performance implications for re-using one ManualResetEventSlim, and resetting it, rather than creating a new ManualResetEventSlim and disposing each time I call this function?

Comment: Is better to reset it, because it's already static, no need to create a new event each time. Anyway I don't think you will notice the difference if you create a new one or reset it. I added a link to see performance boost using ManualResetEventSlim compared to ManualResetEvent.

Comment: Thanks Mihai. Can you comment on the difference between _event.WaitHandle.WaitOne() vs _event.Wait()? They appear to be the same to me.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum  Sorry I was a little busy, I think wait() is based on the WaitHandler internal, I did not check it in depth to see what is doing behind.

Comment: Ok. In the end, I chose to create new ManualResetEventSlim objects rather than reuse a static one, because it's possible that my code might get called in a parallel or multithreaded context by other users in the future. Creating a new ManualResetEventSlim object for each call into my AwaitTemplatePropagation() function should ensure that multiple threads can correctly await propagation of different templates at the same time, I think. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes if you are calling that code from multiple threads is best to have it like a instance member, or use some kind of lock to prevent concurrency.